# top view's touch also works it's bottom view's touch

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

Hi I am facing such issue,

I have two view for example my first view is A which's image is below

[image]

and I am opening View B on this A view

[image]

In view B when i touch the area where there is no button for example

[image]

it's affect to View A, means A view's button clicked, how to avoid this can any body help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the background of the keyboard isn't clickable it goes through to the next layer. Simply set the background/panel of the keyboard as clickable by android:clickable="true", this will prevent the lower layer from being clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Rawa let me check

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! Please, accept my answer aswell and Good luck with your app!